# Missing exception - Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Abstractions.Services.IContentTestingService.GetMultivariateTestDatasource

Tags: sxa

I was extending Sitecore `CopyGlobalDatasource` functionality.

It was working fine, but recently I can see issue while browsing any page through the Experience Editor. Seems like missing method or proper initialization.

Anyone got a similar issue? I'm still trying to find the solution

```
Exception: System.MissingMethodException
Message: Method not found: 'System.String Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Abstractions.Services.IContentTestingService.GetMultivariateTestDatasource(Sitecore.Data.ID, Sitecore.Data.Items.Item, Sitecore.Data.ID)'.
Source: Sitecore.XA.Feature.Composites
   at Sitecore.XA.Feature.Composites.Pipelines.GetXmlBasedLayoutDefinition.InjectCompositeComponents.ProcessCompositeComponent(GetXmlBasedLayoutDefinitionArgs args, XElement rendering, XElement layoutXml)
   at Sitecore.XA.Feature.Composites.Pipelines.GetXmlBasedLayoutDefinition.InjectCompositeComponents.Process(GetXmlBasedLayoutDefinitionArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
```

Comment: Thanks, Marek for updating the question

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this issue, here are the details, Hope that will help to Sitecore colleagues.

The issue was because of the wrong version of `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Abstractions.dll`

I did use version `4.8.1.0`

The actual version should be `4.9.0.0`

This particular method was missing `GetMultivariateTestDatasource` doesn't exist in  version `4.8.1.0`

Here is the comparison -

[image]

I was using the previous version and didn't see any issue, It started recently When I was extending `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.LocalDatasources.Pipelines.CopyGlobalDatasource` and it would (Updated version) need when we open any page in the experience editor.